# Cleaning big data with Hive

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, data-cleaning

I'm using Hive to query data that I have. The problem is, this data needs to be cleaned and it's way too big for me to try and process it on my computer (hence using Hadoop and Hive). Is there a way for me to do this with Hive? I looked into user defined functions but my understanding is that they operate row by row so might not be an optimal way to clean the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should clean your data using a MapReduce program. Probably don't even a reducer which would increase your performance.

The MapReduce program works like a bufferedfile reader, reading one line of data at a time. You can perform your cleaning operation on each line, and then insert it into a hive table for querying.

Answer (score 1):

```
what is your data size?
what is your cleaning operation?
```

If your cleaning operation can not be done with the help of Hive then only go for mapreduce/pig.

If your problem is performance of hive, try to optimize it.

Optimization depends on your cleaning operation.you can use `distribution cache`,`map side joins` etc...

Comment: Thanks for answering me. I ended up using streaming to clean the data